# How can I find 32-bit binaries?

Tags: upgrade, gentoo, 64bit

I've just upgraded one of my Gentoo systems from 32-bit to 64-bit.  Now, I need to find any residual 32-bit binaries (mostly user-installed) so I can either re-compile them as 64-bit or install the 32-bit libraries they need.  How do I do that?

A minor complication: this system is a fileserver and provides netboot services for ARM and 32-bit x86 systems, so there are both non-native binaries and binaries that are *expected* to be 32-bit, and I need to exclude the places where those are found from the search.

Comment: Do you want to search through all files or just files in some directories (like ones in your PATH) ?  Have you tried the "file" command?  it would tell you things like: ELF 64-bit or ELF 32-bit  as well as machine type.  If you use a wild card, you might use  something like: "file -- *|grep 32-bit"...?

Comment: All files except the ones where 32-bit binaries are expected (ie. everything except a few specific subtrees).  The upgrade process took care of pretty much everything in `PATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

`find / -type f -executable -exec file {} \; | grep 32-bit`

to find all the 32-bit executables on your system. (You might not want to start at /)

Then just use `sed` to filter out the directories where you are expecting 32-bit binaries